# Flexbox navbar, container and semantics

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navigation, navbar

this is my first question here on stackoverflow. Forgive me in advance if I am not formatting or asking this accordingly.

So, I've seen people building navbars in many ways, specially with flexbox, therefore, I know this topic was mentioned before many times, but, could someone clarify me if:

1. Does the brand/logo on my site have to be inside an `<h1>` tag of any other heading tags for SEO purposes?
2. Is it right to leave the brand/logo outside of the `<nav>` tag?
3. For example (code below), I would set the `<div>` with the `class= container` as the flex container, but then everything in the rest of the site with that same class would get the `display: flex;`too. Would you recommend creating a separate container class to contain the just navbar? I am applying `display: flex;` on the container and `<ul>` as well so all gets on the same line.

Thank you so much for taking the time and reading this and once again, my apologies if this is an old topic. I am trying to organize my code better and understand the best practices.

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <a href="" class="brand">
                Brand
            </a>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">location</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as the SEO, there's multiple ways you can get a better rating. H1 is probably the best, but you can use any of the header tags, and emphasis things like bold, italics, and such.
There's also meta tags that go in the  area, such as

```
<meta name="keywords" content="your keywords here">
```

Using the keywords throughout your page too is a big help too. One of the ways people get big hits on their pages is by adding the name to the link. Like for articles you see online they'll be /name_of_the_article.html this helps a good deal in the search engines.

For the brand/logo, it is a good idea to leave it outside of the nav tag. You may want to put it in its own div or wrap them both up in a div tree so you can position it easier. But if you want the brand/logo to be with the nav bar then you can have it there also.

For the container part, without seeing the css, I would say if they are going to have the same styling, then by all means keep them together. But unless it's all really simple stuff, it's better to give them their own classes as styling for 1 thing, might not fit with another.

If you could make a jsfiddle or codepen it would be much easier to get a picture of what you want specifically regarding the class css.

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you for answering me. I made a codepen project to illustrate it better. In a simple way what I mean is that by making it semantically accurate, it seems i have to end up using even more tags. For example, to make the whole flexbox work, i had to apply it to the container div. If i needed to reuse that again in a section for exemple, it would be configured in a way in which i can't reuse it. The link to it is https://codepen.io/danielkip/pen/LYPJvVm

Comment: With a few changes, I kept the same style, but freed up container class so that it can be used generically. It can probably be cleaned up a little better, but this was a quick mod.
https://codepen.io/Foregotten/pen/QWLVeJp

Comment: Steve, thank you so much for your help and attention. By the way, one of the solutions I tried and kind worked as well was using a container class with the usual ```margin: 0 auto;``` and ```max-width: ``` and applied and id to it with all the flex specifications I needed to reach that "float" effect. This way I could reuse the container class throughout the whole page.

Comment: No prob. Glad I could help. :-) I'm still learning too. It's so much fun.